# Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so' for module DBD::ODBC: libodbc.so.1

Tags: perl, odbc

I have got stuck,whenever i'm trying to run Perl program getting below error.

```
install_driver(ODBC) failed: Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so' for module DBD::ODBC: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
 at (eval 4) line 3
Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at test.pl line 14
```

ldd /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4bbff000)
 libodbc.so.1 => not found
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffd679a7000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f46000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what system type you are using so probably the easiest thing to try is to go to http://www.unixodbc.org/ and see what is available

It's easier usually to find a suitable package that contains the library, ready built

Answer (score 0):

You've somehow got the perl module DBD::ODBC installed but have no version 1 of the ODBC driver manager. Usually when you build DBD::ODBC you tell it where unixODBC is (or it finds it itself) as DBD::ODBC builds against an ODBC driver manager not an ODBC driver. You need to install the unixODBC package (and dev package if you are going to build DBD::ODBC yourself) or find where libodbc.so is really installed on your machine so the dynamic linker can find it.